# C# How to get the current 24 hours time but start at 8 AM

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a table column in which the column will change colour depends on the real-time  24 hours. My code is worked for 8 am until 12 am, but not 1 am until 8 am for the next day. Can someone help me how to code for the next day? Thank you so much

```
if (System.DateTime.Now.Hour >=8 && System.DateTime.Now.Hour <=20) 
{
     td08.Style.Add("background-color", "#000000"); 
}
```

Comment: its hard to know what you are asking,  what does "how to code for the next day?"  mean?

Comment: I think it means 'but no change of color from 1am to 8am.' So, 12am to 1am is a question mark, but probably changed color *through* 12am.

Comment: i'm sorry if my question is not clear as english is not my first language,
It's like this, I have a table in which will display real time data for each hour.. Then, for each hour that already passed, the column will change the color indicate that the time already passed,..
So, in my case, I have an issue when my column did not work when time pass 12 am..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can simplify it to

```
// hours go from 0 to 23.
// from 8am (8) to midnight. at midnight we go back to 0 so we go to the 'else' block.
if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 8)
{
    TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGoldenrod;
}
else
{
    // from midnight (0) up to 8am.
    TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
}
```

But your question does not specify what you need from midnight to 1am. You might want

```
// the midnight hour (babe) OR 8am to midnight.
if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 0 || DateTime.Now.Hour >= 8)
{
    TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGoldenrod;
}
else
{
    // from 1am (1) up to 8am.
    TextBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me ... i'm sorry if my question is not clear as english is not my first language, It's like this, I have a table in which will display real time data for each hour.. Then, for each hour that already passed, the column will change the color indicate that the time already passed,.. So, in my case, I have an issue when my column did not work when time pass 12 am.

Answer (score 0):

your condition works in 8 am to 20. if you want it works for 1 AM to 8 AM you must use this condition :

```
if (System.DateTime.Now.Hour >= 8 && System.DateTime.Now.Hour <= 20)
      td08.Style.Add("background-color", "#000000");// color for 8 to 20
else if (System.DateTime.Now.Hour >= 1 && System.DateTime.Now.Hour < 8)
      td08.Style.Add("background-color", "#000000");// color for 1AM to 8 AM
```

Comment: Thank you so much for replying but I'm sorry that maybe my question is not very clear...i'm sorry if my question is not clear as english is not my first language, It's like this, I have a table in which will display real time data for each hour.. Then, for each hour that already passed, the column will change the color indicate that the time already passed,.. So, in my case, I have an issue when my column did not work when time pass 12 am.

Comment: If my answer is correct please set answer as correct by check tick. C# and SQL use 24h time format. You must use 0:00 to 23:59 instead of AM or Pm.